# vuex mapped namespaced action "is not a function," error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am importing a Vuex module. Everything works fine if I don't namespace it, but when I do namespace it is reports that the action is "not a function." when called.

index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import MainWindow from './modules/MainWindow';
import ArtEditor from './modules/ArtEditor';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
    },
    mutations: {
    },
    actions: {
    },
    modules: {
        MainWindow,
        ArtEditor
    }
});
```

ArtEditor module:

```
const state = {
    selectedColor : "#FFFFFF"
}

const getters = {
    selectedColor: state => state.selectedColor
};

const actions = {
    selectColor({commit}, newColor){
        commit('selectColor', newColor);
        console.log(newColor)
    }
};

const mutations = {
    selectColor: (state, newColor) => state.selectedColor = newColor
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

in Vue component:

```
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex';
...
methods:{
    ...mapActions(['ArtEditor/selectColor']),
    colorChanged(color){
        this.selectColor(color);
    }
},
...
```

when the color is changed, it throws the error `this.selectColor is not a function`. Most of the documentation on namespaced modules either doesn't import external Vuex modules, or uses `dispatch()` instead of `mapActions()`, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: should be ` ...mapActions('ArtEditor', ['selectColor'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is off, you need to either do:

```
...mapActions(['ArtEditor/selectColor']),
colorChanged(color){
    this['ArtEditor/selectColor'](color);
}
```

Or separate the action path while mapping:

```
...mapActions('ArtEditor', ['selectColor']),
colorChanged(color){
    this.selectColor(color);
}
```

See [binding helpers with namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace).

Comment: Thank you! There is quite literally no documentation on this. I also found I can use `...mapActions[{selectColor : 'ArtEditor/selectColor'}]` as well. Again, they don't seem to tell you this anywhere, so it's amazing anybody figured it out at all.